# column displays in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to build a query that displays a first & last name & the label of "opened by". Here's the query:

```
SELECT a.account_id, 
       a.cust_id, 
       a.last_activity_date, 
       a.open_emp_id, 
       Concat(' Opened By ', e.fname, ' ', e.lname), 
       a.avail_balance 
FROM   account a 
       INNER JOIN employee e 
               ON a.open_emp_id = e. emp_id 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM   transaction t 
                   WHERE  t.txn_date = a.last_activity_date);
```

It works great except that the column label says `CONCAT(' Opened By ', e.fname, ' ', e.lname)` instead of just `e.fname` & `e.lname`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `AS` keyword to name your columns:

```
SELECT a.account_id, a.cust_id, a.last_activity_date, a.open_emp_id, 
CONCAT(' Opened By ', e.fname, ' ', e.lname) AS opened_by, a.avail_balance
FROM account a INNER JOIN employee e
ON a.open_emp_id = e. emp_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
FROM transaction t
WHERE t.txn_date = a.last_activity_date);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an alias:

```
CONCAT(' Opened By ', e.fname, ' ', e.lname) AS opened_by
```

You can now refer to that result as if it was from a column named `opened_by`

Comment: lol. I frequently have other answers posted before mine simply because I am a lousy at typing. Which is ironic considering i do it for living.

Answer (score 2):

Use an alias...

```
...
Concat(' Opened By ', e.fname, ' ', e.lname) AS 'openedBy',
...
```

Comment: I have a related question. Is it possible to have a subquery that displays the customer name using the first & last names if it's an indivdual or the business name, labeling either as Customer. I can't quite how to combine this: SELECT c.cust_id, c.cust_type_cd, 
    CONCAT('Customer', i.fname, ' ', i.lname) as Customer,
    b.name business_name
FROM customer c LEFT OUTER JOIN individual i
    ON c.cust_id = i.cust_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN business b 
    ON c.cust_id = b.cust_id;  with the above.

Comment: Just use `CASE` to determine whether it's individual or business, then display the `CONCAT` or business name.